# Using Linq to object, how can I get one field's value based on another in the same list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a class that is defined as following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a logic where I build a list of that class:

```
MyList = new List<MyClass>;
foreach(MyClassData myClass in Service.MyClassList)
{
    MyList.Add(new MyClass{ID = myClass.ID, Name = myClass.Name});
}
```

Now, I need to get an 'ID' based on the 'Name'.

I'm trying the following:

```
int id01 = MyList.Where(x => x.FileName.Equals("File01")).Single(x => x.FileID)
```

Doing that I'm getting an error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

How would I do that using LINQ?

Comment: int id01 = MyList.Where(x => x.FileName.Equals("File01")).Select(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault();  Do not know where you are getting FileID (should be just ID)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118(v=vs.110).aspx) method's is:

> ```
> public static TSource Single<TSource>(
>   this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
>   Func<TSource, bool> predicate
> )
> ```

It gets a predicate that should return a boolean but you are returning an integer. It is used for filtering and not projecting.

What you are looking for is:

```
int id01 = MyList.Single(x => x.FileName.Equals("File01")).FileID;
```

Or better use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
int id01 = MyList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FileName.Equals("File01"))?.FileID;
```

*Also see if you want the `SingleOrDefault` or the `FirstOrDefault`*